# Is there any alternate way to open external link other then iframe which can allow sameorigin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am loading external links using iframe with onclick of links but we all know that iframe will not load sameorgin links or website can any one suggest a alternate way 
1. to load urls and 
2. if any event occurs inside it, I can detect it

below is the code I created with iframe, in the below one 1st link will work but the secon link2 will not work due to sameorigin

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('title');
    console.log(url);

    $("#siteloader").html('<iframe src="' + url + '" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="siteloader">
  <a href="#" title="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">link1</a>
  <a href="#" title="http://www.google.com">link2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I'm afraid this is not possible. The `X-Frame-Options` restriction will stop the content being displayed, and even if it was shown then the [Same Origin Poliy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) would stop the events being caught in the parent page. Why do you need this?

Comment: I am creating a single page application, where the  url will not change in the header location

Comment: So why do you need to open wikipedia in an iframe? If you need to get data from Wikipedia you could use their API instead

Comment: its just an example for no sameorgin and sameorgin, do we have any alter nate way to load external  links which can be supported in all mobile device

Comment: No, sorry. That's the whole point of `X-Frame-Options`